# Unable to use any of the shaders

Tags: materials, shaders

Only one material node is shown and when I try to add a shader or something, "shaders" is gone. My material panel is also messed up, it used to look different but something happened.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are inside Blender Render engine, switch it to Cycles

Comment: @SergeL Thanks so much, that fixed it